# Count number of non-blank columns and assign to individual respondents

Tags: r

I am trying to get a total number of friends that will become the denominator in a later step.

example data:

```
  set.seed(24)  ## for sake of reproducibility
 n <- 5
data <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
               Q1= c("same", "diff", NA, NA, NA),
               Q2= c("diff", "diff", "same", "diff", NA),
               Q3= c("same", "diff", NA ,NA, "diff"), 
               Q4= c("diff", "same", NA, NA, NA))
```

i first need to create a column that contains a numeric count of how many columns each participant responded to (either "same" or "diff", not counting NAs/blanks). I have tried the following

```
  friendship <- total.friends <- rowSums(c(data$Q1, data$Q2, data$Q3, data$Q4)), != "")
  friendship <- total.friends <-rowSums(!is.na(c(data$Q1, data$Q2, data$Q3, data$Q4)))
```

Neither is effective, likely because my data is not numeric. the first did count the cells but did not group by id as I require. is there any function i can use to count the populated cells? how can i edit this to count cells populated only with "diff" so that i can then start on the second step (making the proportion)?

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
data2 <- apply(data[,-1],MARGIN=1,function(x){c <- length(x[!is.na(x)])})
result <- as.data.frame(cbind(data[,1],data2)) %>% setNames(c("id","number"))
```

And result will hold the amount of not NA each id has.

The data2 is basically a count of the number of not NAs for each id, it uses the apply function with margin 1 which basically takes each row of your dataframe and applies a function to that row. The function that is being applied is the `c<-length(x[!is.na(x)]` part. Which basically, the 'x[!is.na(x)]' filters away all the NA entries in each row so that it only has NOT NA entries of the row, then we apply the length() function to that result so it gives us how many entries where there after filtering the NAs.

The result of that apply will be a single column array, in which each row is the result of computing that procedure to each row, and considering you have a row for each id. It translates as computing that function to each id

Lastly, in the result line I simply add the id back to the previous step, for the sake of having in it well identified and not just one column of results.

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I have one follow up question that may be very basic but i can never deduce it from reading other people's questions. what are the "x"'s in the function and length part of apply, are they where i specify the specific variable for the function to act on (ex. function (data$Q1)) or are we supposed to leave it as x? i ask because these items are columns in a bigger dataframe and i'm not sure how to select them and only them

Comment: X in a function() inside a lapply/map/mapply/map_dfr means the iteration element. For example, writing `lapply(c(1,2,3,4),function(x){print(x)})` is the same as writing `for (x in c(1,2,3,4){print(x)}`. So x will hold one element of the iteratable object, in this example the iteratable object was the vector c(1,2,3,4). In the answer above the iteratable object is data[,-1] which means a matrix of all columns of data except the first one, and the iteratable elements in that iteratable object are the rows. So x will be a row of data[,-1]

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish this using `c_across` and `rowwise` from the `dplyr` library:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Total = sum(!is.na(c_across(Q1:Q4)))) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Note: alternatively you can use `starts_with("Q")` inside of `c_across` to do this across all columns that start with "Q" (shown below).

---

To count the number of a specific response you can do or compute other variables that depend on a newly created variable, like a proportion, in the `mutate` statement:

```
data %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Total = sum(!is.na(c_across(starts_with("Q")))),
                Diff = sum(c_across(starts_with("Q")) == "diff", na.rm = T),
                Prop = Diff / Total) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()

     id Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4    Total  Diff  Prop
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <dbl>
1     1 same  diff  same  diff      4     2  0.5 
2     2 diff  diff  diff  same      4     3  0.75
3     3 NA    same  NA    NA        1     0  0   
4     4 NA    diff  NA    NA        1     1  1   
5     5 NA    NA    diff  NA        1     1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex solution with `grep`:

```
data$count <- apply(data, 1, function(x) length(grep("[a-z]", x, value = T)))
```

Here using `length` you count the number of times `grep` finds a lower-case letter in any row cell.

Result:

```
data
  id   Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4 count
1  1 same diff same diff     4
2  2 diff diff diff same     4
3  3 <NA> same <NA> <NA>     1
4  4 <NA> diff <NA> <NA>     1
5  5 <NA> <NA> diff <NA>     1
```